# What's the proper adjective associated with Seattle?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

I wonder what the proper adjective associated with Seattle is. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adjectivals_and_demonyms_for_cities) claims it is *Seattlite*, however [wordsense](https://www.wordsense.eu/Seattleite/) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Seattleite#:%7E:text=A%20native%20or%20inhabitant%20of%20Seattle.) just say this is a noun (demonym). An autochthon from Seattle also told me:

> I lived in Seattle for 24 years, that's not how it's used. – [Azor Ahai -him-](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/32836/azor-ahai-him) [15 mins ago](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/168518/why-must-hotel-customers-check-out-after-a-stay-longer-than-a-rather-low-number?noredirect=1#comment420011_168518)

So what's the proper adjective associated with Seattle?

[Example of use](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168518/1810):

> I was surprised to read that hotel customers must check out after 13 days at the **Seattleite** hotel and 4 weeks at the Californian hotel.

Comment: Indeed, even  "Californian" to describe a hotel stuck out to me, but I'm not from California so I didn't comment. I don't think there are many adjectives in English that would be used this way to describe that a place is located somewhere. To me, "an American hotel" sounds more like a hotel in the American style located somewhere else, rather than a hotel located somewhere in America. Since you posted on ELL, I wonder what your first language is and whether it has constructions in this style

Answer (score 6):

As pointed out by ColleenV in the comments, both "Seattle" and "California" are most idiomatically used as [noun adjuncts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) in this context, i.e. you can say "the Seattle hotel" or "the California hotel."

Comment: But not Hotel California (!)

Answer (score 1):

A person might be a Seattleite (although this isn't a particularly common demonym)  Not a hotel.  The -ite suffix refers to people who are members of certain groups.

There isn't really a common adjective form, similar to "Californian". And "Californian" may indicate a style, rather than a location (in this case though the context makes it clear). So simply

> ...hotel customers must check out after 13 days at the hotel in Seattle ...

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "after 13 days at Seattle hotels, and 4 weeks at California hotels" though.

Comment: @ColleenV Grammatically, no, but it would be slightly ambiguous as to whether the rule applies across hotels or in only one (which is what the context was)

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- "hotel customers must check out after 13 days at the Seattle hotel and 4 weeks at the California hotel." would be OK too.

Comment: @ColleenV Sorry, I meant "Grammatically, yes"

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I think you got it right the first time - I'm just being too terse because I'm doing multiple things at once. I meant "the ambiguity would be resolved by writing..." :)

Comment: @ColleenV that should be an answer

Comment: @ajd Not by my standards. If you want to write a proper answer explaining "Seattle hotel", feel free.